# Excel - How to determine the number of "A"s in one column based on a specified date range in another?

Tags: excel, date, countif

I have 2 columns on excel, one with referral dates, the other with referral source. It looks something like this:

[image: img]

I would like the count the number of the different referral source based on the different years.

So far I've tried to look for solutions but only have come up with various dead ends. I've tried something like this.

```
IF(AND(C2:C20>DATE(2011,1,1),C2:C20< DATE(2011,12,31)),COUNTIF(D2:D20,"A"))
```

However all it does is return the total number of "A"s in D2:D20, and does not factor in the condition of the date range. I definitely must have missed something out.

Some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need >= and <= on your dates to include the first and last day of the year. Then you can use COUNTIFS which is counting with multiple criteria.

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C20,">=" & DATE(2011,1,1),C2:C20,"<=" & DATE(2011,12,31),D2:D20,"A")
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind, can you mark this as the answer. Thanks.